# Из dupenv собрать путь в filesystem

Tags: c++, файловая-система

Есть вот такой набросок кода.

```
char *pValue;
char *pValue1;
size_t len;
_dupenv_s( &pValue, &len, "base_dir" );
_dupenv_s( &pValue1, &len, "job_name" );
```

Из полученных значений пытаюсь собрать путь, но получается только вот так :

```
std::experimental::filesystem::path path_job;
path_job = pValue1;
path_job /= pValue;
```

Т.к. если писать в одну строчку появиться ошибка, что так нельзя. Может есть способ в одну строчку записать и не плодить перезаписывание в другие типы и `/=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так.

```
auto path_job = std::filesystem::path(pValue1) / pValue;
```

filesystem уже в стандарте, experimental не нужен.

Comment: Работает, но `experimental` использую т.к. на linux в Clion просит его, хотя update делал и вот такие настройки в CmakeLists.txt установил
`set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` и `link_libraries(stdc++fs)`